# Express as a complex Fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

My function is $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{1-2e^{ix}} + \dfrac{1}{1-2e^{-ix}} $, which has been periodically extended by $2\pi$.

I found $C_0$ to be $\pi$. I'm having trouble expressing $C_n$.

All I have is

$$C_n = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \! \dfrac{4-2cosx}{5-4cosx} e^{-inx} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

where I added the fraction to get

$\dfrac{2-e^{ix}+2 - e^{-ix}}{4 + e^0 - 2e^{ix} - 2 e^{-ix}} $

I've messed around with it for a long time but I can't figure out where to go. Any help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the expansion
$$
\frac1{1-2\exp(ix)} = -\frac 12 \exp(-ix) \frac1{1-\frac 12 \exp(-ix)}
= -\frac 12 \exp(-ix) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{2^n}\exp(-inx)
$$

so 
$$
\frac1{1-2\exp(-ix)} = -\frac 12 \exp(ix) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{2^n}\exp(inx)
$$

and you can easily check that the convergence is uniform:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\left|\frac 1{2^n}\exp(inx) \right|
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{2^n}<\infty
$$
hence you can invert integral and summation in the definition of $c_p$:

$$
c_p = \frac 1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi
\exp(-ipx) f(x) dx 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\=
\frac 1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp(-ipx)
\left[-\frac 12  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{2^n}\exp(-i(n+1)x) 
-\frac 12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac 1{2^n}\exp(i(n+1)x)
\right] dx
%%%%%%%%%%%
\\= -\frac 12  \sum_{n=0}^\infty 
\frac 1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp(-ipx)
\left[\frac 1{2^n}\exp(-i(n+1)x) \right] dx +\\
-\frac 12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty 
\frac 1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp(-ipx) \left[
\frac 1{2^n}\exp(i(n+1)x)
\right]\exp(-ipx) dx
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\= \frac1{2^{p-1}} 
$$if $p\neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise.